# How to use eternicode bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have been unable to get even the basic calendar pop-up to occur.  Here are the scripts I have, and the code:

```
Note: I am using jquery 1.10.2 and it is included first.

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/override.css"));

        <div class="input-group date">
          @Html.TextBox("ForesterDate", today, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

and at the bottom of the page, in script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

The textbox looks to be styled correctly, but clicking does no good.  I thought maybe it was a razor issue, so I made a textbox with html, no change:

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be where I had my script tag.  This is my first MVC5 app, and I guess you can't just tack it to the bottom of your view anymore, it has to be in a @section() which is rendered at the bottom in the _include.